# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1062] Shipping method is not available

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, soap-api-v1

Why only `flatrate_flatrate` in array shipping Method?

I set the customer and address is successfully.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => flatrate
            [carrier_title] => Flat Rate
            [code] => flatrate_flatrate
            [method] => flatrate
            [method_description] => 
            [price] => 5.0000
            [error_message] => 
            [method_title] => Fixed
            [carrierName] => Flat Rate
        )

)
```

Shipping method: `flatrate_flatrate`

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1062] Shipping
>   method is not available in /var/www/html/market/mboh.php:118
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /var/www/html/market/mboh.php(118): SoapClient->__call('call', Array)
>       #1 /var/www/html/market/mboh.php(118): SoapClient->call('65d0a95484ac4eb...', 'cart_shipping.m...', Array)
>       #2 {main}
>         thrown in **/var/www/html/market/mboh.php** on line **118**

Comment: Can you pls help me with following error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/249612/57334  @Vishwas Bhatnagar